# Normalize in canonical form two XML files in Python

Tags: python, xml, canonicalization, canonical-form

I have two XML files and I need to check that they contains the same exact information.

Regardless of tag or attribute order.

For instance this two XML files should be equals:

**test1.xml**

```
<blocklist lastupdate="1459262434336" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/2006/addons-blocklist">
  <emItems>
    <emItem blockID="i454" id="sqlmoz@facebook.com">
      <versionRange minVersion="0" maxVersion="*" severity="3">
        <targetApplication id="{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}">
          <versionRange maxVersion="3.6.*" minVersion="3.6"/>
        </targetApplication>
      </versionRange>
      <versionRange maxVersion="*" minVersion="0"/>
      <prefs>
        <pref>test.blocklist</pref>
      </prefs>
    </emItem>
  </emItems>
</blocklist>
```

**test2.xml**

```
<blocklist lastupdate="1459262434336" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/2006/addons-blocklist">
  <emItems>
    <emItem blockID="i454" id="sqlmoz@facebook.com">
      <prefs>
        <pref>test.blocklist</pref>
      </prefs>
      <versionRange minVersion="0" maxVersion="*" severity="3">
        <targetApplication id="{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}">
          <versionRange maxVersion="3.6.*" minVersion="3.6"/>
        </targetApplication>
      </versionRange>
      <versionRange minVersion="0" maxVersion="*"/>
    </emItem>
  </emItems>
</blocklist>
```

I tried to find some solutions like:

- [xmldiff](https://www.logilab.org/859)
- [lxml-c14n](http://www.decalage.info/fr/python/lxml-c14n)
- [xml.dom](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/python-cookbook/0596001673/ch12s09.html)

I am also going to try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33521000/186202)

But do you have any idea of what would be my options here? Isn't XML Normalization and Canonicalization supposed to handle this for me?

what am I doing wrong here?

If I were to do it in JSON I would use: `json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True, separators=(',', ':'))`

Comment: What about http://pastebin.com/HVJ0mwK7?

Comment: How does it validate that attributes are equals?

Comment: Sorry, read it wrong.  Easy to modify,  pull tags,  values and sort

Comment: You can actually do it without sorting and lazily evaluating the second file,  i will add the code when i get back on my laptop

Comment: If you really don't care about where the tags appear you can do something like http://pastebin.com/TH7MtHYb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who are interested on this subject, I created a `xml-verifier` script that does that by converting the xml into a JSON file and then exporting both file as Canonical JSON and doing a diff of them.

https://github.com/mozilla-services/amo2kinto/blob/1.7.2//amo2kinto/verifier.py#L80-L108

Comment: The link is dead, sadly

Comment: Nice catch, fixed.