# Anaconda code for comparing two xmls and output the differences

Tags: python, anaconda

Can anyone help me in getting the Python code for comparing two XMLS and output the differences in log file . I'm new to python I have already tried the code in this link ([Comparing two xml files in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24492895/comparing-two-xml-files-in-python)) in anaconda python 3.5.2 but it throws me exception. 
I have tried the below code in anaconda , but it throws me syntax error in 
def **init**(self):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import logging

class XmlTree():

    def __init__(self):
        self.hdlr = logging.FileHandler('xml-comparison.log')
        self.formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')

    @staticmethod
    def convert_string_to_tree( xmlString):

        return ET.fromstring(xmlString)

    def xml_compare(self, x1, x2, excludes=[]):
        """
        Compares two xml etrees
        :param x1: the first tree
        :param x2: the second tree
        :param excludes: list of string of attributes to exclude from comparison
        :return:
            True if both files match
        """

        if x1.tag != x2.tag:
            self.logger.debug('Tags do not match: %s and %s' % (x1.tag, x2.tag))
            return False
        for name, value in x1.attrib.items():
            if not name in excludes:
                if x2.attrib.get(name) != value:
                    self.logger.debug('Attributes do not match: %s=%r, %s=%r'
                                 % (name, value, name, x2.attrib.get(name)))
                    return False
        for name in x2.attrib.keys():
            if not name in excludes:
                if name not in x1.attrib:
                    self.logger.debug('x2 has an attribute x1 is missing: %s'
                                 % name)
                    return False
        if not self.text_compare(x1.text, x2.text):
            self.logger.debug('text: %r != %r' % (x1.text, x2.text))
            return False
        if not self.text_compare(x1.tail, x2.tail):
            self.logger.debug('tail: %r != %r' % (x1.tail, x2.tail))
            return False
        cl1 = x1.getchildren()
        cl2 = x2.getchildren()
        if len(cl1) != len(cl2):
            self.logger.debug('children length differs, %i != %i'
                         % (len(cl1), len(cl2)))
            return False
        i = 0
        for c1, c2 in zip(cl1, cl2):
            i += 1
            if not c1.tag in excludes:
                if not self.xml_compare(c1, c2, excludes):
                    self.logger.debug('children %i do not match: %s'
                                 % (i, c1.tag))
                    return False
        return True

    def text_compare(self, t1, t2):
        """
        Compare two text strings
        :param t1: text one
        :param t2: text two
        :return:
            True if a match

xml1 = "<note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>"

xml2 = "<note><to>Tove</to><from>Daniel</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>"

tree1 = XmlTree.convert_string_to_tree(xml1)
tree2 = XmlTree.convert_string_to_tree(xml2)

comparator = XmlTree()

if comparator.xml_compare(tree1, tree2, ["from"]):
    print "XMLs match"
else:
    print "XMLs don't match"
        """
        if not t1 and not t2:
            return True
        if t1 == '*' or t2 == '*':
            return True
        return (t1 or '').strip() == (t2 or '').strip()
```

Comment: please share your code and the error you get

Comment: @Tomaž Bratanič updated the code and error