# Getting Element tree object doesn't have a tag attribute in the below python code

Tags: python

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import logging

class XmlTree():

    def __init__(self):
        self.hdlr = logging.FileHandler('xml-comparison.log')
        self.formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')

    @staticmethod
    def convert_string_to_tree( xmlString):

        return ET.fromstring(xmlString)

    def xml_compare(self, x1, x2, excludes=[]):
        """
        Compares two xml etrees
        :param x1: the first tree
        :param x2: the second tree
        :param excludes: list of string of attributes to exclude from comparison
        :return:
            True if both files match
        """

        if x1.tag != x2.tag:** Error occuring Line**
            self.logger.debug('Tags do not match: %s and %s' % (x1.tag, x2.tag))
            return False
        for name, value in x1.attrib.items():
            if not name in excludes:
                if x2.attrib.get(name) != value:
                    self.logger.debug('Attributes do not match: %s=%r, %s=%r'
                                 % (name, value, name, x2.attrib.get(name)))
                    return False
        for name in x2.attrib.keys():
            if not name in excludes:
                if name not in x1.attrib:
                    self.logger.debug('x2 has an attribute x1 is missing: %s'
                                 % name)
                    return False
        if not self.text_compare(x1.text, x2.text):
            self.logger.debug('text: %r != %r' % (x1.text, x2.text))
            return False
        if not self.text_compare(x1.tail, x2.tail):
            self.logger.debug('tail: %r != %r' % (x1.tail, x2.tail))
            return False
        cl1 = x1.getchildren()
        cl2 = x2.getchildren()
        if len(cl1) != len(cl2):
            self.logger.debug('children length differs, %i != %i'
                         % (len(cl1), len(cl2)))
            return False
        i = 0
        for c1, c2 in zip(cl1, cl2):
            i += 1
            if not c1.tag in excludes:
                if not self.xml_compare(c1, c2, excludes):
                    self.logger.debug('children %i do not match: %s'
                                 % (i, c1.tag))
                    return False
        return True

xml1 = "File1.xml"
xml2 = "File2.xml"

tree1 = XmlTree.parse(xml1).getroot()
tree2 = XmlTree.parse(xml2).getroot()

comparator = XmlTree()

if comparator.xml_compare(tree1, tree2, ["from"]):
    print "XMLs match"
else:
    print "XMLs don't match"
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, there's no `parse()` method in `XmlTree` class, so I suppose what you want is

```
tree1 = ET.parse(xml1).getroot()
tree2 = ET.parse(xml2).getroot()
```

By the way maybe you should declare `self.logger` in `__init__` method by

```
def __init__(self):
    self.hdlr = logging.FileHandler('xml-comparison.log')
    self.formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
    self.hdlr.setFormatter(self.formatter)

    self.logger = logging.getLogger("Sample")
    self.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    self.logger.addHandler(self.hdlr)
```

---

Here is the full code, it works well in both Python2.x and python3.x:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import logging

class XmlTree():

    def __init__(self):
        self.hdlr = logging.FileHandler('test.log')
        self.formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
        self.hdlr.setFormatter(self.formatter)

        self.logger = logging.getLogger("Sample")
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        self.logger.addHandler(self.hdlr)


    @staticmethod
    def convert_string_to_tree( xmlString):
        return ET.fromstring(xmlString)

    def xml_compare(self, x1, x2, excludes=[]):
        """
        Compares two xml etrees
        :param x1: the first tree
        :param x2: the second tree
        :param excludes: list of string of attributes to exclude from comparison
        :return:
            True if both files match
        """

        if x1.tag != x2.tag:

            self.logger.debug('Tags do not match: %s and %s' % (x1.tag, x2.tag))
            return False
        for name, value in x1.attrib.items():
            if not name in excludes:
                if x2.attrib.get(name) != value:
                    self.logger.debug('Attributes do not match: %s=%r, %s=%r'
                                 % (name, value, name, x2.attrib.get(name)))
                    return False
        for name in x2.attrib.keys():
            if not name in excludes:
                if name not in x1.attrib:
                    self.logger.debug('x2 has an attribute x1 is missing: %s'
                                 % name)
                    return False
        if not self.text_compare(x1.text, x2.text):
            self.logger.debug('text: %r != %r' % (x1.text, x2.text))
            return False
        if not self.text_compare(x1.tail, x2.tail):
            self.logger.debug('tail: %r != %r' % (x1.tail, x2.tail))
            return False
        cl1 = x1.getchildren()
        cl2 = x2.getchildren()
        if len(cl1) != len(cl2):
            self.logger.debug('children length differs, %i != %i'
                         % (len(cl1), len(cl2)))
            return False
        i = 0
        for c1, c2 in zip(cl1, cl2):
            i += 1
            if not c1.tag in excludes:
                if not self.xml_compare(c1, c2, excludes):
                    self.logger.debug('children %i do not match: %s'
                                 % (i, c1.tag))
                    return False
        return True

    def text_compare(self, t1, t2):
        """
        Compare two text strings
        :param t1: text one
        :param t2: text two
        :return:
            True if a match
        """
        if not t1 and not t2:
            return True
        if t1 == '*' or t2 == '*':
            return True
        return (t1 or '').strip() == (t2 or '').strip()


xml1 = "1.xml"
xml2 = "2.xml"


tree1 = ET.parse(xml1).getroot()
tree2 = ET.parse(xml2).getroot()

comparator = XmlTree()

if comparator.xml_compare(tree1, tree2, ["from"]):
    print("XMLs match")
else:
    print("XMLs don't match")
```

1.xml

```
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
</note>
```

2.xml

```
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>
</note>
```

Comment: I modified the code as per your suggestion. But still getting the same problem. I'm trying to run this code in Anaconda python 3.6 whether that is creating any problem. Actually i took this code from this stack exchange post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24492895/comparing-two-xml-files-in-python. Could you please help me with this case. I'm a beginner level in python doesn't have much programming background.

Comment: @DineshKumar `print "XMLs match"` it will return SyntaxError in Python3.x.

Comment: Can the above the code able to iterate all the tags in the XML or i should rewrite it, why because i doubt in the line (if x1.tag != x2.tag:** Error occuring Line**) as it keeps erroring there.

Comment: @DineshKumar I edit my answer, have a look, the code works well. So maybe there's something wrong elsewhere in your project.