# Web-scraping using Python: Checking change in XML structure everyday

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to implement a web scrapper wherein I would like to get the XML of a page and store that into some data structure (considering dictionary in python) and then check for any change in the structure of the page, like a change of any div or any attribute inside the div block.

I do not want to check for the change of contents but just the overall structure of the page.

Since I am new to web-scrapping, I would like to ask what should be the best way to implement this?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Research making requests with Python, as well as parsing XML in Python.

Comment: Solution found at:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24492895/comparing-two-xml-files-in-python